# Highcharts: Heatmap using CSV

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I am trying to load data via CSV file.  Now if I have it already on the page as a hidden div, it works great.  But trying to load it from a CSV file via Jquery $.get is not working.  The x and y axis shows, but the heatmap itself does not.

The javascript looks like this (without the actual file offhand):

```
$.get('http://www.urltofile.com/cell001.csv', function(csv) {
  generateHeatMap($('#heatmapBody'),csv);
});

function generateHeatMap(target,data) {
  target.highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        //height: highChartsArguments.chartHeight
        margin: [60, 10, 80, 50]
    },
    boost: {
        useGPUTranslations: true
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts extended heat map',
        style: {
            color: 'black',
            fontSize: '12px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'text',
        min: 0,
        max: 427,
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 5,
            y: 14,
            format: '{value}' // long month
        },
        showLastLabel: false,
        tickLength: 16
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        },
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickPositions: [0, 16, 32, 48, 64, 80, 96, 112, 133],
        tickWidth: 1,
        min: 0,
        max: 133,
        reversed: true
    },
    colorAxis: {
        max: 1.5,
        min: -1.5,
        minColor: '#00FF00',
        maxColor: '#FF0000',
        stops: [
            [0.0, '#00FF00'],
            [0.5, '#003319'],
            [0.9, '#FF0000'],
            [1, '#FF0000']
        ]
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        symbolHeight: 60
    },
    series: [{
            name: 'heatmap',
            data: {
                csv: data
            },
            boostThreshold: 100,
            borderWidth: 0,
            nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: 'Test<br/>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x} {point.y}: <b>{point.value}</b>'
            },
            turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE // #3404, remove after 4.0.5 release
        }],
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    }
  });
}
```

The CSV is over 100K rows.  Is that causing a problem perhaps?  As a sample, it looks like

```
Gene,Label,zScore
0,0,3.630958
0,1,1.547901
0,2,-0.604027
0,3,0.486755
0,4,-0.359456
0,5,0.228968
0,6,3.197601
0,7,1.554732
0,8,0.374111
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what errors do you see in the console?

Comment: @inspired Interestingly enough, there are no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load the data incorrectly. Series object is not responsible for handling csv data. If you use [data module](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E), you should move the data from series options to top level options, like this:

```
  data: { // this is how you load the with data module
    csv: data
  },

  series: [{
  ... // here, options for series goes but not data
  }]
```

Compare your code with the official example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/heatmap/

Comment: Thank you so much!  As a newbie with highcharts, I appreciate this!